# Como enviar sons personalizados nas notificações para o FCM via HTTP legacy?

Tags: php, firebase, http

Estou utilizando um APP padrão webview com integração ao FCM; e sempre enviei as notificações para os usuários através do site com protocolo HTTP legacy. Continua funcionando normalmente, porém os sons personalizados e armazenados na pasta RES/RAW do app só tocam nos usuários com Android 7.2 ou inferior; no Android Oreo e superior só toca o som padrão. Não a nada na documentação informando sobre isso. Sei que o problema ocorreu para notificações locais também e fora solucionado adicionando os canais de notificação. Porém no FCM http legacy não encontrei nada que pudesse solucionar o problema.

```
    include('banco_dados.php');

$consulta = mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT controle, apelido FROM usuarios WHERE id= '$id'");
$dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
$controle = $dados['controle'];
$apelidomsg = $dados['apelido'];

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
$registrationIds = $controle;

 $msg = array
      (
    'body'  => $apelidomsg,
    'title' => $title,
    'icon'  => 'myicon',
    'sound' => $sonido,
    'tag' => 'skp'
      );

$fields = array
        (
            'to'        => $registrationIds,
            'notification'  => $msg
        );


$headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```